# Make a new line at TextBox and clear RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox

I have a problem with my project.

Whenever I use the button, it must rec the date. But when I do a lot of rec, it appears on one line. What I want is that if a click a button, it will make a new line.

The picture shows the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZWFb.png

Problem 2:

If I rec any date, the app should close and reopen to show in the log.

If I delete any date I should the close app and open it to show the list is clear.

---

I hope you can help me because I'm try to fix it but I can't.

This is the code:

https://www.mediafire.com/?3ponbn53ar1ybpd

Comment: You should post the code, it makes it easier to reference in the future.

Comment: i put all code because i dontknow  where is the problem

Comment: I meant you should post all the code in the question or at least parts that are relevant. Later after you fixed your problem, many people remove the links to their code which then means we are left with a question but no references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, just indicate a new line such as using `Environment.NewLine`.

```
   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Windows\Help\log.txt", TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine, True)
```

I don't exactly understand your second problem but if the file is located in your system, it should store the information/data properly.

Comment: not working with me :( the second proplem if i click button clear it is not clear but i should to close app and open it again to complete clear

Comment: Which one? The first or the second?

Comment: in rec date out can i make the (( eat )) in one line with date  for example : 
out06:50:00 م04-11-2014eat

Comment: Yes ofcourse, just remove the newline in the first writeAllText. So you have : My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Windows\Help\log.txt", TextBox1.Text, True)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Windows\Help\log.txt", TextBox2.Text & Environment.NewLine, True)

Comment: i want if i Click on ((show log)) it is reloading the log.txt in the RichTextBox1

Comment: try to click at rec date enter and click (( delete all log )) then enter the password 411399    the file will deleted from system file put the data still view at RichTextBox1 --- i want if i             click (( delete all log )) the file will deleted from system file  & the RichTextBox1 came clear without any data

Comment: Add `Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = ""` after `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Windows\Help\log.txt")`

Comment: can i use the Islamic date in my app ??

Comment: The Hijri Calendar right? You can find the answer here http://forums.asp.net/t/1442100.aspx?Convert+Gregorian+to+Hijri+Date.

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Windows\Help\log.txt", TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine, True)                                                            how to edit this to working with Hijri Calendar ??

Comment: Well I am not familiar with that, but I'm sure the answer is in the link that I've provided above.

Comment: can i make a 2 line ??